# I have recorded an excel vba sort but don't understand the code lines

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, therefore i often record anything in excel and use the recorded code. Unfortunately I do not understand the following sort code.

```
Private Sub SortType()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "C6:C" & usedRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B6:T" & usedRows)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

What does the first line `Sort.SortFields.Clear` (and do I really need it?) and for what do I need the With-method?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line clears any existing sort information (note it does not actually sort anything). The With block simply saves writing the `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort` part on each line inside that block. Without it the code would have to be:

```
Private Sub SortType()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "C6:C" & usedRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SetRange Range("B6:T" & usedRows)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.Header = xlGuess
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.MatchCase = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.Apply
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> What does the first line Sort.SortFields.Clear

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195810%28v=office.15%29.aspx), *The SortField object contains all the sort information for the Worksheet, ListObject, and AutoFilter objects*.

So it removes any existing `AutoFiltering` etc.

> And for what do I need the With-method?

It tidies up code (ie else your lines would be longer such as `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Sort.SetRange Range("B6:T" & usedRows)`, but when using the macro recorder there is often redundant code contained inside the `With`

As an example your could trim your code down like this:

*recut*

```
Sub BottomUp()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Requirements")
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[B6], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp))
rng1.Sort ws.[c6], xlAscending
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your link really intended to lead back to this post? Just wondrin, or you accidentally pastes the wrong link?

Answer (score 1):

`SortFields` is a collection of values that describe what columns in a sorted range are sorted and in what fashion, it therefore makes sense to remove any of this data before performing a new sort.

`With .. End With` is syntactic short-hand that simply saves repeatedly typing the object name that follows the opening `With` statement.